# Is the numbers of primes that is sum of 2 + another prime is finite?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In order to have sum of $2$-primes to be a prime one of the primes must be the prime $2$. However the "distance" between adjacent primes increases as we search along the natural numbers.

For example
The number of primes in the range: $10^5:10^5+100$ is $6$

The number of primes in the range: $10^7:10^7+100$ is $2$ $(10000019, 10000079)$

Is it possible we have finite numbers of this type?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime

Comment: It is conjectured to be infinite. I would say that due to the definition of `increase`, the statement `the "distance" between adjacent primes increases as we search along the natural numbers` is false.

Comment: The distance between adjacent primes increases *on average*.  You'll see the actual individual distances jump about quit a bit.  For the first 25 primes the distances are 1,2,2,4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,4,2,2,6,4,2,6,4,4,2,8. See how the numbers gradually get larger and larger numbers become more common but the small numbers never stop?

Answer (score 2):

These are known as Twin Primes, and the question you are asking about is still unresolved, though I believe that most mathematicians suspect that their are indeed infinitely many such primes.